# Has anyone installed elementary OS on the Lenovo Yoga 910 yet?

Tags: lenovo

I'm curious if there are any known issues? And how does it handle flipping into tablet mode, etc?

Answer (score 1):

Just installed it on the 910 dual boot with Win10.  Only issue at this point is getting the wifi to work.  I can BT to my mobile device to get connected but its slow.  Wifi works perfectly under win10.  I have searched everywhere for a resolution with no resolve. Updated firmware did not fix.  I think there is conflict with the 2-in-1 having multi network cards, one for ideapad and the other for laptop.

Answer (score 0):

**Auto rotate not working**, as was mentioned on Lenovo forum, everything else should work well, after install try **update linux kernel** to latest version.

Just guessing, nothing easier then install and try on your own.

Comment: Where did you find this thread on the Lenovo forums? I can't find any thread where someone has done this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to answer my own question as I make progress. So far no luck, the installer can't find the hard drive and even booting into Live mode, it has no driver for the Qualcomm Atheros wireless card so you'll have no wifi.

Related forums:

Lenovo is releasing new BIOS's for some machines that allows you to install Linux, but they don't have one for the 910 yet:

- https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Linux-Discussion/Installing-Ubuntu-16-04-on-Yoga-900S/m-p/3466862#M8629
- https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Lenovo-Yoga-Series-Notebooks/Yoga-900-and-Ideapad-710S-Linux-Only-BIOS/tac-p/3574443#M388

To be continued...